# Track on window rusted out

Tags: toyota, corolla, window, rear

I have a 1993 Toyota Corolla hatch, I have been trying to purchase a rear passenger window for awhile now and no one seems to have on, I have the window but the track on the bottom is rusted out ,is there a way I can make one, any suggests will be appreciated . Thank you.

Comment: Can you transfer it from the old window?

Comment: I am finding all kinds of right rear windows on eBay. Looks like 1993 to 1997 all used the same glass. What exact model is yours (DX Wagon 5-door, All Track Wagon 4-door)?

Comment: As you say your existing track is rusted out then it can’t be swapped over... But have you checked out a scrap or breakers yard? Maybe you can find a good one. Or, is it a simple U channel that you can make? The rubbers can sometimes be found on ebay...

Comment: @Debbie A picture might be nice to help explain here